# Execute script when click Save in Edit page AdminBro

Tags: javascript, express, hook, admin-bro

In documentation, AdminBro said that they have predefined action

> edit (record action) - update records in a resource

They also have hook `after`. So I define a function and assign it to `MyResource.edit.after`. The problem is this function not only execute when I save changes after edit, but also when I go to Edit page, that's not what I want.

How can I run this function only when I click `Save Button`  on Edit page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
Use `before` instead of `after` and compare `request.method` to `POST` in parameters

Comment: This is working but i think this make requirement to operate wrongly ,
i want to only call my custom function after the record successfully Edit .